# info.plist for different target version

Tags: ios

One of my project needs to provide lite/full version and english/french version. 
I know that localise and set info.plist/InfoPlist.strings for different luanguange.
But if I also hope to set the info.plist for different target version(lite/full).
How can I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you create a new target Xcode will make a copy of the `info.plist` for the new target. In the target build settings you can even change the name of the `info.plist` used for that target.

The default name of the `info.plist`  is something like `copy-info.plist` when you rename the file on the file system make sure that you also rename it in the build settings. The build setting key you need to change is `Info.plist File`.

Comment: if I set InfoLite.plist for the lite version, what is about the InfoPlist.strings? how to rename it?

Comment: Just place it in a separate directory called Lite or something then exclude the the `InfoPlist.strings` from the other target and include the `InfoPlist.strings` from the lite version.

Comment: nice answer..what to do if `InfoPlist.strings` is localized and already present in `en.lproj/` + `da.lproj/`